# $d(X_n, Y) \to 0$ implies convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have the following metric:
$$d(X,Y) = E\left(\frac{|X-Y|}{1+ |X-Y|}\right)$$
I woud like to prove that 
$$d(X_n , Y)\to 0 \implies X_n \xrightarrow{P} Y$$

I would like to use the theorem that says 
$$ X_n \xrightarrow{L^p} Y \implies X_n \xrightarrow{P} Y$$

So, the problem is to prove that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} E\left(\frac{|X_n-Y|}{1+ |X_n-Y|}\right)=0 \implies\lim_{n\to \infty} E\left(|X_n-Y|^p\right)=0 $$

but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Indeed $$d(X_n , Y)\to 0 \implies X_n \xrightarrow{P} Y$$ holds and $$ X_n \xrightarrow{L^p} Y \implies X_n \xrightarrow{P} Y$$ holds but there is no chance that $$d(X_n , Y)\to 0 \implies X_n \xrightarrow{L^p} Y$$ could hold. Did you check any simple examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Did pointed out in a comment, your proposed strategy won't work. But you can get the result by more or less unpacking the definitions and using the fact that $P(A) = E(\mathbf{1}_A)$. Here's a sketch.

$$P(|X_n - Y| \geq \epsilon) = E(\mathbf{1}_{|X_n - Y| \geq \epsilon}),$$

so

$$\frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon}P(|X_n - Y| \geq \epsilon) \leq E \Big( \frac{|X_n - Y|}{1 + |X_n - Y|} \mathbf{1}_{|X_n - Y| \geq \epsilon} \Big).$$

We can make the right-hand side as small as we want, so
$$\frac{\epsilon}{1 + \epsilon}P(|X_n - Y| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\epsilon^2}{1 + \epsilon},$$

and then $P(|X_n - Y| \geq \epsilon) \leq \epsilon.$